Python scripts not running from command line on W11 without "python" prefix
My (work) computer recently updated from Win 10 to Win 11. For the most part the process was painless, but Python is causing me pain.
I need to run multiple versions of Python (2.7 - for legacy stuff - and a bunch of 3.x), so I have virtual environments configured for the versions and environments of Python that I need to run.
Under Windows 10, I needed to prefix my python scripts with "py" when running them in a command window. My solution here was to create a batch file to start a command window for whatever version of python I wanted to run.  This batch file associated files with a .py extension with "py", the python launcher, and then activated the appropriate virtual environment. i.e.
assoc .py=Python.File 
ftype Python.File="C:\Windows|py.exe" "%1" %*
 
...

<path to virtual env>\Scripts\activate.bat

That worked fine in Windows 10.When I wanted to run a script I just typed <script_name.py args> and my script ran.
Under Windows 11 now, with the same launch script, I need to prefix every script with "python" before it will run.
It does not matter if the python install or the virtual environment existed  before or was installed/created after the Win 11 update - the behaviour is the same for both.
I've not come across any reports of similar behaviour,here or in the wider internet.

A typo in "C:\Windows|py.exe"? Use \ (U+005C,  Reverse Solidus)
instead of | (U+007C,  Vertical Line). The following works for me: Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*

Check whether set pathext contains .py extension (mine is PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PHP).

Thanks JosefZ. You are correct, the '|' is a typo in the post and is actually a '' in the script. Hopefully I've typed it correctly this time. On the PC in question pathext includes ".py". I'm still scratching my head on this one.

I've struggled with this too recently.
The solution I've found was to ensure that the "Python" version that's associated with Python files, is the one with a rocket in its icon.
